# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type (BoomMenu Flutter)

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am currently making a mobile app in flutter, which has a boomMenu, I would like to add a 'FutureBuilder' within this menu, this is possible, when I try to do it I get the following error:

> The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type

**This is my code: **

```
BoomMenu buildBoomMenu() {
  Expanded(child:
  FutureBuilder(
      future: stationSvc.getStations4(http.Client()),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        try {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .size
                  .height / 1.3,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "   Cargando....",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 25,
                    ),
                    SpinKitCubeGrid(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(16, 71, 115, 1)
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
          return snapshot.data.length > 0
              ? ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return BoomMenu(
                    animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
                    animatedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 152.0),
                    //child: Icon(Icons.add),
                    onOpen: () => print('OPENING DIAL'),
                    onClose: () => print('DIAL CLOSED'),
                    scrollVisible: scrollVisible,
                    overlayColor: Colors.black,
                    elevation: 10,
                    overlayOpacity: 0.7,
                    children: [
                      MenuItemModel(
                        title: snapshot.data[index].devicename!,
                        titleColor: Colors.grey[850]!,
                        subtitle: snapshot.data[index].devicename!,
                        subTitleColor: Colors.grey[850]!,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50]!,
                        onTap: () => print('THIRD CHILD'),
                        elevation: 10,
                      ),
                      MenuItemModel(
                        title: "List",
                        titleColor: Colors.white,
                        subtitle: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur",
                        subTitleColor: Colors.white,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                        onTap: () => print('FOURTH CHILD'),
                        elevation: 10,
                      ),
                      MenuItemModel(
                        title: "Team",
                        titleColor: Colors.grey[850]!,
                        subtitle: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur",
                        subTitleColor: Colors.grey[850]!,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50]!,
                        onTap: () => print('THIRD CHILD'),
                        elevation: 10,
                      ),
                    ]);
              })

              : Center(
              child: Text('No hay datos, registra un grupo primero'));
        } catch (Exc) {
          print(Exc);
          rethrow;
        }
      }),
  );
}
```

This is my service 'getStations4()':

```
Future<List<Stations>> getStations4(http.Client client) async {
final response = await client
    .get(Uri.parse('URL'));

// Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
print(compute(parseStations, response.body));
return compute(parseStations, response.body);
}

List<Stations> parseStations(String responseBody) {
final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>> 
();

return parsed.map<Stations>((json) => 
Stations.fromJson(json)).toList();
 }
```

Images of the boomMenu:

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you add getStations4 too?

Comment: Sure, let me update the post

Comment: could you say how do you use buildBoomMenu?

Comment: The 'boomMenu', I'm putting it as a floatingActionButton, I want to place data in the BoomMenu that I get from a json, I have this data in the FutureBuilder section. Please let me know if I understood your question correctly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't return anything, it doesn't know where to start. you need to return the expanded widget at the top level, and make the return type Widget. Because if your future fails, its not returning a BoomMenu, its returning a Text widget.

```
Widget buildBoomMenu() {
  return Expanded(child:
  FutureBuilder(
      future: stationSvc.getStations4(http.Client()),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It shows me the next error... 'A value of type 'Expanded' can't be returned from the method buildboommenu, because it has a return type of BoomMenu'

Comment: Thanks Jack. i tried it, but, it returns the next error..... ' Null check operator used on a null value '

Answer (score 0):

Change your `buildBoomMenu` to this:

```
Widget buildBoomMenu() { //<--- change this
  return Expanded(child://<--- add this
     FutureBuilder(
      ...
     )
   );
}
```

your first issue is that you forgot the `return` keyword, the second one is that your `buildBoomMenu` return type is `BoomMenu` but you are returning other widget so I recommended to change it to `Widget`, like above.

Comment: Hi eamirho3ein, thanks for your answer, i tried it, but, it returns the next error..... ' Null check operator used on a null value '

Comment: where is this error happened?

Comment: This error appears when I try to enter the page where the floatingActionButton is located .... 'BoomMenu'. The screen turns red and sends that error